# Hypergeometric function asymptotics

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, asymptotics, hypergeometric-functions

I came across the following hypergeometric function recently: 
$$
_2F_1(1-n,p-2n+1;p-n+1;x)
$$
where $p > 0$ is a non-integer constant, $n$ some large positive integer, and $x > 0$ a small constant.

I'd like to know its growth order. I am expecting it to decay like $(1-x)^{2n}$ or so but I have no idea how to prove it. Invoking the identity
$$_2F_1(a,b;c;x) = (1-x)^{c-a-b} {}_2F_1(c-a,c-b;c;x)$$
I get
$$
_2F_1(1-n,p-2n+1;p-n+1;x) = (1-x)^{2n-1} {}_2F_1(p,n;p-n+1;x)
$$
so I am expecting that when $n$ is sufficiently large, $_2F_1(p,n;p-n+1;x)$ grows very slowly (with respect to $n$), slower than $n^{p-\epsilon}$ for some small $\epsilon$ that may depend on $x$ and $p$. I tried numerical values in Mathematica, and it seems that $_2F_1(p,n;p-n+1;x)$ is positive, slowly increasing and upper bounded by $1$ when $n$ is sufficiently large. In fact, proving it is upper bounded by some constant (could depend on $p$ and $x$) would be already good for me.

I tried to expand it into series and compared the term of the same index for $n$ and $n+1$, but this did not work.

If it is well-known, can anyone point me to some reference?

Comment: It's not explicitly stated in your question what kind of growth are considering, forcing the readers to guess. Do you mean growth in $x$, growth in $n$, or something else? Also, are considering the growth wrt one variable, with all others fixed, or do you need some uniform bound with respect to some domain of the remaining variables?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine sorry, I've updated the question. Growth is w.r.t. $n$ and the constant bound can depend on $p$ and $x$.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [DLMF§15.12](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12), in particular at formula 15.12.7. Though, there the large parameter may have the sign opposite to yours. Still, at the bottom of that page, there are also some hints about how to combine their formulas and some transformations to obtain other asymptotic forms.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Thanks for the reference. Just curious, is there a simple way to say, for instance, for all large $n$, $_2F_1(p,n;p-n+1;x)$ have the same sign?

Comment: All I can say that it would be simple for me.

Comment: typically one would take an integral representation of the function, and use a method for integral asymptotics. E.g. if you use Euler integral representation for $_2 F_1(c-a,...;x)$ you'd expand the term $(1-xt)^{-c+a}$ into a series and take the biggest terms to get an asymptotic expansion by integration.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik doesn't expanding $(1-xt)^{-c+a}$ in integral representation recover the series definition of hypergeometric function?

Comment: wait, isn't your function a polynomial of degree $n-1$? For small $x$ only linear term matters...

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Yes, it is; but I need some behaviour that could be claimed independent of n. For instance, my question is equivalent to say, the smallest root of the polynomial is at least some constant (depending on $x$ and $p$) for all large $n$. You would need smaller and smaller $x$ for larger and larger $n$ to make the approximation valid, which wouldn't give anything I want. Linear approximation gives that the root is approximately $x\approx 2/(n-1)$ for large $n$, but this does not seem to be the case by looking at the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1(p,n;p-n+1;x)$.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik I was hoping that writing it as hypergeometric function could be useful so that there are more known results. For instance, a very old paper from 1898 showed that there is only one root in $(0,1)$ for all even $n$ (or odd, depending on $p$) and there is no root in $(0,1)$ for $n$ of the other parity.

Comment: Never mind... I've solved the problem using the relations among contiguous hypergeometric functions